# Listview/Recycler View is not expanding in Scrollview/NestedView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I tried list and recycler view in both scroll/nestedscroll view, height of list is not expanding properly. If i hard code height of list than it works otherwise wrap content not working. 
I searched a lot on internet, due to listview in scroll view and both objects have scrolling abilities that is why one object dont let other to scroll. That is why height of listview is not working. I know its bad practice but i dont have a choice my layout contains several objects like checkbox and edittext. And i need to scroll other objects too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns-android="http-//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns-app="http-//schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android-isScrollContainer="false"
        android-layout_width="match_parent"
        android-layout_height="match_parent"
        android-layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android-clipToPadding="false"
        app-layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android-layout_width="match_parent"
            android-layout_height="match_parent"
            android-orientation="vertical"
            android-paddingTop="1dp">

     <ListView
        android-id="@+id/list"
        android-layout_width="fill_parent"
        android-layout_height="match_parent"
        android-divider="@null" />
         </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You will need to set a fixed height to the listView, whats the problem with that?

Comment: I believe RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView should work, but you would need to call `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)`.

Comment: I can accomplish "m vai"'s statement. The RecyclerView seems to be much more reliable in combination with the CollapsingToolbar.

Comment: items in list is dynamic, items generate at run time that is why i cant fix the height

Comment: i also tried recyclerview same result

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the property `fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <com.example.NestedListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and:

```
public class NestedListView extends ListView implements View.OnTouchListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope that's help